# use react-grid-layout multiple times in one another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grid, react-grid-layout

Is there a way to use multiple react-grid-layout components in one another?

I use this: https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout

Or can I define a specific anchor to drag the items?

Thanks